# Retornar la segunda propiedad de un objeto si se cumple una condicion

Tags: javascript, objeto, ecmascript-6

Tengo un arreglo que tiene tres objetos dentro, y necesito recorrerlo y si el type de uno de los objetos es "wikipedia" devolver solo su url y guardarla en otro objeto como un string... de esta forma:

```
let movie = {
   "url": "https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dark_Knight"
}
```

////codigo

```
        let webs = [
        {
        type: "imdb",
        url: "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0468569/"
               }
        { 
        type: "wikipedia",
        url: "https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dark_Knight"
        },
       {
       type: "rottentomatoes",
       url: "https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/the_dark_knight"
       }
       ]
```

lo que hice fue usar el metodo find pero me devuelve el objeto entero con el type y no solo la url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

el find efectivamente te devuelve el objeto entero, pero podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```
let movie = webs.find(movie=>movie.type==="wikipedia").url
```

Eso sería suficiente para devolver el value del segundo key. Sinó podrías para que quede más legible quizás y dejarlo en objeto como necesitas hacer algo como:

```
searchedMovie = webs.find(movie=>movie.type==="wikipedia")
let movie = {movie: searchedMovie.url}
```

o directamente:

```
searchedMovie = webs.find(movie=>movie.type==="wikipedia").url
let movie = {movie: searchedMovie}
```

Espero te ayude, buena jornada!

Comment: tambien podes hacer let { url } = webs.find(movie=>movie.type==="wikipedia")

Comment: Es muy buena opción la que sugiere Facundo, por las dudas agrego que lo que hace se llama desestructuración, de esa forma obtiene solo url del objeto resultante en el find, ese url luego puedes utilizarlo para armar tu objeto final.

Comment: claro, esto te permite hacer  cosas como -- >  let { url, type } = webs.find(movie=>movie.type==="wikipedia")  y de esa forma, ya tienes 2 variables llamas url y type y estas obtienen los valores del objeto.

Comment: Muy buen aporte!

Comment: Gracias, con estos ejemplos aprendi un monton!! Saludos

Answer (score 2):

Aqui te dejo dos versiones con metodos de array, espero te sean de utilidad.

```js
let webs = [{
  type: "imdb",
  url: "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0468569/"
}, {
  type: "wikipedia",
  url: "https://es.wikipedia.org/wikipedia/The_Dark_Knight"
}, {
  type: "rottentomatoes",
  url: "https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/the_dark_knight"
}, {
  type: "wikipedia",
  url: "https://www.wikipedia.com/wikipedia/the_dark_knight_Dos"
}

]


//Forma 1, fija solo primer resultado.
let resultado = webs.find(item => item.type === "wikipedia").url
console.log(resultado)

//Forma 2, todos los resultados.
resultado = webs.filter(item => item.type === "wikipedia").map(item => item.url)

console.log(resultado.map(item => item))
```